# Switch language and capitalize letter smoothly

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, manjaro

I come from Windows Background So I'm used to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for switching language and I used GNOME tweaks to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> work in Linux.

However, when I switch language, I hold on the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to capitalize the next letter but it doesn't capitalize. I have to release my hand from the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key first which is very annoying.

I'm using Manjaro Linux with GNOME desktop

Comment: Works here in XFCE/Fedora. TEST